# Firebug: is there any shortcut for "Resend"

Tags: firebug

Im just wondering if there is any shortcut for resending the reques that are shown inside "Console", ajax requests for example.

Answer (score 0):

The [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel) only offers to re-execute the last command executed in the [*Command Line*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line) via the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

If you want to resend a network request, right-click on it and choose *Resend* from the context menu. This works for all network requests within the *Console* panel as well as the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel).

Furthermore note that AJAX requests are the **only** network requests shown within the *Console* panel.

This was already [answered in similar words in the Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebug/mYDh2RmqSKs).